# I want to load image from Firebase to my app without making any categories in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to load image from Firebase to my app without making any categories in Firebase like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcTKC.jpg)

Instead, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDNHE.jpg) is what's happening

Below is my source code, thank you in advance

**model class code**

```
public class model
{
  String url;

    public model() {
    }

    public model(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

**Fragment Class firebase code**

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("games"),**model**.class)
.build();

adapter = new myadapter(options);
```

**My Adapter class code**

```
public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,myadapter.myviewholder> {

    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull model model) {
        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getUrl()).into(holder.img);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerowdesign,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView img;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to load image from Firebase to my app without making any categories in Firebase

If you only want to add key-value pairs under the "TEST" node, there is no need to use the "model" class at all. You can simply use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference testRef = rootRef.child("TEST");
testRef.child("a").setValue("https://imageurl.com/xx1.jpg");
```

However, when using the Firebase-UI library to read the values under "TEST", you should create a new instance of FirebaseRecyclerOptions using the String class, because all values under "TEST" are String objects and **not** "model" objects.

Comment: I didnt get u can u plz write a sample code...I dont want to use model class

Comment: Have you tried the code that I already provided? There is no model class involved. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: What should I add inside .setValue as I want to get all this info from Firebase dont want to add url here.

Comment: If you'll use the code I provided, you'll get a database schema that looks like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcTKC.jpg)**. Have you tried it?